# Batch n VBS to setup a hotspot

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I wrote a batch file to setup hosted network in Win7-8. 
It used basic commands! I want to do same using VBS.
Basically I want my VBS to gimme an option to

1. SET UP HOTSPOT
2. START
3. STOP
4. SHOW
5. EXIT

1. SET UP: In this I will take input from user SSID and PWD, and of course, at end of every task I'll show a done msg.

I'll have to use `netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=%name% key=%pwd%` in CMD to set up and so on.

Comment: Sounds good. Go do it.

Comment: Consider using a [HTA](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692768.aspx) for this.

Comment: But I dont know even A, B, C of VBS or WSH and can't find on google. Maybe I am googling wrong :P

Comment: I don't want to run it from a browser though... @AnsgarWiechers

Comment: HTA files are self-contained. It's only technically a browser, and it doesn't function as one.

Comment: @SomethingDark  how do I take input from user, like SSID name and pass it into a function as I said above and run it in CMD? A little help? just gimme code to do this one task and I'll follow everything else.. :P TAKE INPUT -> PASS IT ONTO CODE -> DISPLAY RESULT AND RUN CODE IN CMD!

Comment: The best way to find a solution to a programming problem is to google the name of the programming language and what you're trying to do. In your case, search for `vbscript get user input` and you'll find exactly what you're looking for. (You may want to include "console" in the search if you're serious about running it in a command prompt.)

Comment: Also, if batch works, why the switch to vbscript if you want to keep it in the command line? VBS is great for GUIs.

Comment: Because of GUI @SomethingDark

Comment: If you want to build a GUI you need to familiarize yourself with the respective building blocks. For building GUIs with VBScript (i.e. HTA) the building blocks are VBScript, HTML (particularly forms), and CSS. However, SO is not the place to provide you with tutorials for these three languages.

Comment: Yeah I know. I just needed help with one particular thing. Now I am catching on! ^^ Thanks for help. I know PHP, CSS, HTML. Just building this stuff for my younger brother!

Comment: Again, I don't think I can send string to batch from vbs :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This an example in **HTA** that you can be inspired with it to achieve your aim ;)

It show you how you can easily pass commands and execute it, so hope this can give you some ideas ;)

```
<html>
<head>
<HTA:APPLICATION
APPLICATIONNAME="Open links with IE, Chrome and Firefox and how to pass command line"
BORDER="THIN"
BORDERSTYLE="NORMAL"
ICON="Explorer.exe"
INNERBORDER="NO"
MAXIMIZEBUTTON="NO"
MINIMIZEBUTTON="NO"
SCROLL="NO"
SELECTION="NO"
SINGLEINSTANCE="YES"/>
<title>Open links with IE, Chrome and Firefox and how to pass command line</title>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">
'************************************************************************************
Option Explicit
 Function Executer(StrCmd,Console)
    Dim ws,MyCmd,Resultat
    Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
'La valeur 0 pour cacher la console MS-DOS
    If Console = 0 Then
        MyCmd = "CMD /C " & StrCmd & " "
        Resultat = ws.run(MyCmd,Console,True)
        If Resultat = 0 Then
            'MsgBox "Success"
        Else
            MsgBox "Une erreur inconnue est survenue !",16,"Une erreur inconnue est survenue !"
        End If
    End If
'La valeur 1 pour montrer la console MS-DOS
    If Console = 1 Then
        MyCmd = "CMD /K " & StrCmd & " "
        Resultat = ws.run(MyCmd,Console,False)
        If Resultat = 0 Then
            'MsgBox "Success"
        Else
            MsgBox "Une erreur inconnue est survenue !",16,"Une erreur inconnue est survenue !"
        End If
    End If
    Executer = Resultat
End Function
'************************************************************************************
Sub window_onload()
    CenterWindow 480,400
End Sub
'************************************************************************************
Sub CenterWindow(x,y)
    Dim iLeft,itop
    window.resizeTo x,y
    iLeft = window.screen.availWidth/2 - x/2
    itop = window.screen.availHeight/2 - y/2
    window.moveTo ileft,itop
End Sub
'************************************************************************************
Sub Ip_Publique()
    Dim Titre,URL,ie,objFSO,Data,OutPut,objRegex,Match,Matches,ip_public
    Titre = "Adresse Ip Publique !"
    URL = "http://monip.org"
    If OnLine("smtp.gmail.com") = True Then
        Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        ie.Navigate (URL)
        ie.Visible=False
        DO WHILE ie.busy
            Sleep 100
        Loop
        Data = ie.document.documentElement.innertext
        Set objRegex = new RegExp
        objRegex.Pattern = "\b([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b"
        objRegex.Global = False
        objRegex.IgnoreCase = True
        Set Matches = objRegex.Execute(Data)
        For Each Match in Matches
            MsgBox "Votre IP Publique est : "& Match.Value,64,Titre
        Next
        ie.Quit
        Set ie = Nothing
    Else
        MsgBox "Vérifier votre connexion internet puis re-executer ce script",48,Titre
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub

'**************************************************************************************
Sub Sleep(MSecs)'Fonction pour faire une pause car wscript.sleep ne marche pas dans un HTA
    Dim fso,objOutputFile
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim tempFolder : Set tempFolder = fso.GetSpecialFolder(2)
    Dim tempName : tempName = "Sleeper.vbs"
    If Fso.FileExists(tempFolder&"\"&tempName)=False Then
        Set objOutputFile = fso.CreateTextFile(tempFolder&"\"&tempName, True)
        objOutputFile.Write "wscript.sleep WScript.Arguments(0)"
        objOutputFile.Close
    End If
    CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run tempFolder&"\"&tempName &" "& MSecs,1,True
End Sub
'**************************************************************************************
Sub SSID_names()
Dim objShell,fso,File,strContents,objRegEx,objMatch,colMatches
    set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If Executer("netsh wlan show all > Wlan.txt",0) = 0 Then
        Set File = fso.OpenTextFile("Wlan.txt",1)
        strContents = File.ReadAll
        Set objRegEx = New RegExp
        objRegEx.IgnoreCase = True
        objRegEx.Global = True
        objRegEx.Multiline = True
        objRegEx.Pattern = """([^""]+)"""
        set colMatches = objRegEx.Execute(strContents)
        For each objMatch in colMatches
            MsgBox "SSID name: " & objMatch.Value,64,"SSID name"
        Next
    End If
End sub
'***************************************************************************************
Function OnLine(strHost)
Dim objPing,z,objRetStatus,PingStatus
    Set objPing = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}").ExecQuery("select * from Win32_PingStatus where address = '" & strHost & "'")
    z = 0
    Do    
        z = z + 1
        For Each objRetStatus In objPing
            If IsNull(objRetStatus.StatusCode) Or objRetStatus.StatusCode <> 0 Then
                PingStatus = False
            Else
                PingStatus = True
            End If      
    Next    
        sleep 200
        If z = 4 Then Exit Do
    Loop until PingStatus = True
    If PingStatus = True Then 
        OnLine = True
    Else
        OnLine = False
    End If
End Function
'***************************************************************************************
Sub WLAN_Networks()
    If Executer("netsh wlan show profiles > Wlan_tmp.txt & netsh wlan show networks >> Wlan_tmp.txt & netsh wlan show interfaces >> Wlan_tmp.txt & cmd /U /C Type Wlan_tmp.txt > Wlan_Networks.txt",0) = 0 Then
        Call Executer("Start Wlan_Networks.txt & Del Wlan_tmp.txt",0)
    End If
End Sub
</script>
</head>
<p>Links List (examples) :</p>
<ol>
<li><a href="#" onClick="Call Executer('Start iexplore.exe www.google.com',0)">Lien Google avec iexplore.exe</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onClick="Call Executer('Start chrome.exe http://bbat.forumeiro.com/',0)">Lien BBAT avec Chrome.exe</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onClick="Call Executer('Start Firefox.exe www.developpez.net',0)">Lien developpez.net avec Firefox.exe</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onClick="Call Executer('Start chrome.exe www.yahoo.fr',0)">Lien Yahoo avec Chrome.exe</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onClick="Call Executer('Start chrome.exe www.autoitscript.fr',0)">Lien Autoitscript.fr (Français) avec Chrome.exe</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onClick="Call Executer('Start chrome.exe www.autoitscript.com',0)">Lien autoitscript.com (Anglais) avec Chrome.exe</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onClick="Call Executer('Start www.sfr.fr',0)">Lien SFR avec votre navigateur by default</a></li>
</ol>
<BODY text=white bgcolor="DarkOrange" TOPMARGIN="1" LEFTMARGIN="1">
 <center><button onclick="Call Executer('mode con cols=90 lines=15 & Color 0A & Title Ping sur www.stackoverflow.com by Hackoo & Ping www.stackoverflow.com',1)">Ping on www.stackoverflow.com</button><hr>
 <center><button onclick="Call Executer('FindStr /? > HelpFindStrTmp.txt & cmd /U /C Type HelpFindStrTmp.txt > HelpFindStr.txt & start HelpFindStr.txt',0)">Help sur FindStr</button>
 <button onclick="Call Executer('ipconfig /all > configTmp.txt & cmd /U /C Type configTmp.txt > MyIPconfig.txt & Del configTmp.txt & start MyIPconfig.txt',0)">IpConfig</button>
 <button onclick="Call Executer('mode con cols=80 lines=50 & Color 9B & Title Hackoo & netstat -a',1)">Netstat</button>
 <button onclick="Call Executer('mode con cols=60 lines=10 & Color 0A & Title Hackoo & arp -a',1)">Arp</button><hr>
 <button onclick="Call Executer('mode con cols=80 lines=30 & Color 9B & Title Tracert vers www.stackoverflow.com by Hackoo & Tracert www.stackoverflow.com',1)">Tracert to  stackoverflow</button><br><hr>
 <center><button onclick="Call Ip_Publique">IP Publique</button>
 <button onclick="Call SSID_names()">SSID WLAN</button>
  <button onclick="Call WLAN_Networks()">WLAN Network</button>
 </center>
 </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Awesome :P I almost gave up! Although I was not kinda thinking to involve HTA but VBS won't send parameters back to cmd! So this is cool! Will have to do some translations :P